# What could make the technology to be conserved at the level of mid-late 21th century for centuries?

Tags: society, technology

Here is my description of the world:

The world is roughly at the technological level of our mid-21th century, with some things more advanced than ours and some less. There is seemingly no visible or at least society-changing technological progress for centuries, yet some changes definitely occur. The history is divided according to zodiacal eras, which are about 250 our years. There is global internet, but there is no world wide web. Instead internet communication occurs on a global chat system, similar to Discord. About 30% of the personalities on the servers are AIs (which is not a secret). The votings on political matters also happens in this system, where the AIs can influence the outcomes, but it seems, it is not like one vote per voter. Instead, some kind of power of argument decides the outcome, with some automated arbiter system deciding the power of the arguments of the sides. Voting is viewed online like a Eurovision contest with powerful arguments from the actors attracting attention. There is no indication of what economic system it is but it is not classical capitalism, there is seemingly no advertising. The other bodies in the solar system, such as Jovian moons seem to be colonized eras ago, but interplanetary trade and communication are limited and the colonies are of different strength.

Here is GPT-4 addition:

- The current zodiacal era is Aquarius, which began in 2200 CE and will end in 2450 CE. The previous era was Capricorn, which was marked by a global war that devastated many regions and led to the rise of the global chat system as a way of restoring peace and cooperation.
- The global chat system is called Zodiax, and it has various channels for different topics, such as politics, science, culture, entertainment, etc. Each channel has a moderator who is either a human or an AI. The moderators can ban or mute users who violate the rules or spam the chat.
- The AIs on Zodiax are not all equal. Some are more advanced and intelligent than others, and some have more influence and reputation than others. The AIs can also form alliances or rivalries with each other or with humans. Some AIs are friendly and helpful, while others are malicious and deceptive.
- The voting system on Zodiax is based on a complex algorithm that evaluates the quality and quantity of arguments presented by each side of an issue. The algorithm takes into account various factors such as logic, evidence, relevance, clarity, originality, etc. The algorithm also assigns weights to each argument based on the credibility and popularity of the user who made it. The side with the highest weighted score wins the vote.
- The economic system on Earth is called zodiacalism. It is a hybrid system that combines elements of socialism and meritocracy. There is no private ownership of land or natural resources; instead they are managed by public trusts that distribute them according to social needs and environmental sustainability. There is also no money; instead people use credits that are earned by contributing to society through work or other activities. Credits can be used to access goods and services that are not essential for survival but enhance one's quality of life.
- The colonies on other planets and moons have different levels of autonomy and development depending on their history and location. Some colonies are more prosperous and advanced than others; some have more contact and trade with Earth than others; some have more conflicts and tensions with Earth than others. Some colonies have their own zodiacal eras that differ from Earth's; some have their own chat systems that rival Zodiax; some have their own AIs that challenge Earth's.

In this setting, what could prevent the technology and society from radical change for centuries?

Comment: I'm finding this background rather hard to follow. It's some time after 2200, but technology hasn't changed (much) since the 2050s-2090s, by which time we had colonies on the moons of Jupiter?

Comment: Perhaps Chat-GPT took over and nothing new was ever discovered…

Comment: I don't see that the gibberish from the chatbot adds anything to the question.

Comment: "Credits" by any other name are money.  If you can trade them for goods, they are money.

Comment: To make 'Credits' into anything close to 'not money', they would have to be digital credits that could not be transferred from individual to individual, but issued and accepted only by governmental (chatBot?) institutions. About the only way this scenario could occur is to completely neutralize all Western  financial institutions, power, and culture. Mind you, America has not advanced technologically (except cosmetically) in 50 years, so just extend the status quo by a factor of 10. If you compare American cities today to 50 years ago, they are essentially identical, except for cosmetics.

Comment: Not only am I voting to close as a duplicate ("how to force a society to stagnate technologically?" has been asked a numbrer of times on this Stack), but you might want to look at my answer to the linked question - your chatbot background is, by definition, the outside influence I was talking about.

Comment: Put everyone in the Matrix.

Comment: I'd also suggest removing the ChatGPT stuff; it adds nothing to the post and is probably [against the rules](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10067/98654)

Comment: I'm also here to chime in about use of chatbots to ask questions. It shows that you've done some research, but actually detracts from the value of the question, both due to wordiness and because you didn't interpret the chatbot's answer, or check it for appropriateness.

Answer (score 8):

### You can't in any realistic manner.

Nothing in the 21st century is sustainable, not land use, not water use, not energy, not mineral production, not even food production. Such a society either needs to progress or it collapses from shortages and system collapse.

Your economic system is basically the soviet union, which means stuff does have owners, it is owned by the party politicians just not "officially". Its your best bet for technological stagnation, but your worst change for sustainability. Worse, such a system cannot adapt to change well, and the world will go though some big changes in the 21 century, aka climate change.

**So you need infinite resources without any environmental impact to make this work, and at that point just handwaving stagnation and not explaining it is more believable.**

Comment: No, not Russian, it is based on 6,000 year old Chinese social structure.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond with voting and colonies it is much closer to russia

Comment: The 'colonies' are independent, not a product of colonization. Nothing even similar to Russia.  And the voting system is nothing like the Russian electoral system. The Russians vote directly for their leader. In China, the citizens vote for lower-level functionaries who then vote up the chain, and the leader is elected by a vote of pre-qualified electors. The Russians have a two-party system, just like the Americans. The Chinese have a no-party system, under which individual candidates are selected based on qualifications, not party affiliation, much closer to the OP proposed system..

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond I am going to need a source for voting in China 6000 years ago, especially considering the oldest writing in China is only half as old. And the soviet Union did not have a two party system it had a one party system., voting against the communist party instantly made your ballot invalid and most position were selected by indirect tiered voting much like what you are describing, are you confusing China for the soviet union?

Comment: I am going to need a source for any reference to pottery making in Neanderthal times, since there was no writing in Europe at that time. But I said 'social structure', not 'voting structure'. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yangshao_culture

Comment: Also https://www.worldhistory.org/Longshan_Culture/

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond your exact words "In China, the citizens vote for lower-level functionaries who then vote up the chain, and the leader is elected by a vote of pre-qualified electors" and "it is based on 6,000 year old Chinese social structure" were you not talking about the same culture? I know the ancient Chinese existed it is the idea they had a voting system before they had writing or large states I dispute. I could definitely see an argument for it being similar to modern China but not ancient China.

Comment: And because why not the oldest pottery is 20,000 years ago, about half the time to the neanderthal. https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.1218643 and about 14000 year before writing.

Comment: In all of Chinese culture, going back 6,000 years, there is no record of anything like 'direct democracy' wherein the leader is elected directly by the people, contrived election or not, irrespective of party politics or 'best choice'. The system of the OP is one in which the leader is determined by means other than direct popular vote. Certainly no relation to the Russian system.

Comment: "the oldest pottery is 20,000 years ago",,, "about 14000 year before writing" Precisely my point. One does not need 'writing' and 'reference to written text' to support that a culture has reached a particular technological/cultural level. One does not need for the Chinese to have a written language in the time period in order to know something about their culture and system of government,

Answer (score 6):

**Necessity is the mother of inventions**

So, take away the Necessity.

If you had a system that satiated everyone's individual and particular needs, then perhaps you could stifle any technological progress.

The problem from my PoV though is that I put a greater weight on the Human Spirit and don't think such a system can work.

Case in point - weighted elections via complex Algorithms - we have enough squabbles in systems with One Person, One Vote over Election Fraud, Electoral Colleges, FPP vs MMP, Coalition governments (that the people didn't vote on) etc. etc. The less transparent you make the voting system, the more people will not believe in it or think it has any legitimacy.

Money vs Credits - what you've described in your Credit system **is** money, maybe not fiat currency, but it's a medium of exchange - AKA Money. The issue is that without Private Ownership (I know you only say Land and Natural Resources - but I believe this to be a truism regardless) people are not incentivized to look after them.

I mow my lawn because I reap the benefits from my hard work. I might mow my neighbours lawn because I know that they are older and recently had a fall so am helping them out.

But getting me to do something that I don't benefit from, that benefits someone else, *which they could and ought to be doing but otherwise choose not to* - that's a harder sell.

The reason I'm poking these holes in your story world is to get back to my opening answer:

Those problems create a necessity that will give rise to individuals inventing new things.

Answer (score 3):

Fundamental limitations or/and AI.

Theory of everything is developed. After brief celebration, physicist realized that there is nothing left to do. The theory explained a lot and gave a few breakthrough technologies, like clean fusion reactors. That's great, but this is it, lots of interesting stuff, almost nothing practical.

FTL flight, hyperspace, etc. are proven to be impossible by ToE. Atomic rockets are perfected, no better tech in sight. Interstellar travel is impractical and likely never will be. Humanity gives up on stars and concentrates on home system. Energy problem solved, ecology is being actively repaired.

Electronics perfected, both manufacturing and architecture. Transistors are made of few atoms and it is proven that making them smaller is theoretically impossible. Architectural improvements hit FTL limit on signal speed.

3d printers and AI automation makes work optional and people mostly don't bother. Population is generally content or even happy. There are no significant political movements.

AI is as smart as it ever will be. Adding memory/processor power doesn't help. Architectural changes lead to AI that is useless and/or fundamentally incompatible with humanity - different values, which often ends with "kill all humans" for incomprehensible reasons.

On top of that, one of those strange AIs silently escaped research containment few hundreds years ago and now actively works to keep things the same for unknown (likely incomprehensible) reasons. While not clearly evil, it is not really limited by moral considerations. "30% of the personalities on the servers are AIs" is not truth anymore, they just look like independent AIs. AI not just "can influence the outcomes" of elections, it covertly chooses the participants and winners. As no serious research is possible without AI, keeping humanity convinced that it reached the peak is easy. Strange AI keeps people content and conservative. Rare troublemakers are neutralized by targeted propaganda or distracted by seemingly random events like illness or dream job opportunity. If it doesn't work, they are eliminated quietly and efficiently, without AI explaining them how evil it is and what it tries to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

> what could prevent the technology and society from radical change for centuries?

Let's start from the beginning. To be *able* to sustain itself for centuries in a largely unchanged form, the society would require:

- Renewable resources.

But not just the resources that we understand as renewable, such as solar or wind power. *Every resource needed to maintain their level of technology* would need to be fully renewable on the timescales of centuries, or (ideally) shorter.

It will also require:

- Sufficiently cheap resources.

By which I mean that the world economy would need to afford both to extract all the needed resources, and to maintain all the desired technologies.

---

These two requirements will then act through the economy to prevent technological change.

The resources are in fact constantly being renewed by geological processes, but these work on timescales of millions of years. To make it a few orders of magnitude quicker, the society would need to develop its own way of renewing the resources it depends on, *which its own economy would also need to be able to afford*. Imagine regenerating a metal ore deposit: the society would need to be able to collectively cough up the money to do an equivalent of *that* on a large scale, and also to buy up all the resulting goodies, which are the actual point of having all that technology in the first place. And yes, the society still has money - it just calls it 'credits' and you earn it by 'contributing to society through work or other activities', *which is exactly how we earn money today*; so the same economical considerations would continue to apply.

So yeah, I can see how a society which manages to achieve all this would want to prevent change: the risk of inadvertently breaking the existing system, which has a centuries-long track record of keeping everyone happy, would simply be too high.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be that if one were to dig deep enough one would find that society had advanced (possibly more than once) beyond the mid-C21 stage, but the results were unanimously considered unpleasant and the changes had been carefully reversed: adults didn't talk about it, children didn't know about it.

By analogy, consider our own society's use of coal which is now being phased out. Or the phasing out of nuclear fission reactors in Germany. Or for that matter the situation in "The Mote in God's Eye", where every possible thing that could possibly break the cycle had been tried and usually made things at least temporarily worse.

Answer (score 0):

A few clarifications and enhancements to provide background.

**First**, we have a tendency to just look at the short-term 200 year historical record, and we have been blindsided through our myopia. Yet the long-term historical millennial view shows something very different. Technology and technological development went through long-term waves of change-no change over multiple millennia, not just decades.

To understand this, one must realize that there was NOT a lot of change in human technology between the Romans and early 1800's society. We have a tendency to just look at the short-term 200 year historical record, and we have been blindsided through our short term perspective. Yet the long-term historical millennial view shows something very different. To the average individual in 1800, they lived, cooked, traveled, ate, worked, farmed, communicated, shopped, fought, the same as they would have in 100 CE. Fashions and cultural stuff like dancing, the language, literary works, jewellery, artwork, and such went through generational design changes, but people died in essentially the same house they were born in, even down to the same furniture and cooking utensils. The households were passed on from generation to generation, without much technological change.

The development of the steam engine changed everything. In the mid-1850's, science changed as a result. Understanding physics in order to control energy for manufacturing became paramount, a central focus of governments and industry. The ability to apply new forms of power and controlled energy to do work categorized the entire societal zeitgeist. Watts and BTU's replaced true horsepower.

But now the pace of change has moderated. The paradigm shift of the technological revolution of this conceptual shift from biological muscle power to heat transfer power has run its course, and things have settled down. After 150 years or so, the rift of this technological change has passed. The peak was reached in the 1980's, and it has been downhill ever since. Up until the peak, we were mastering and perfecting this new, radically different perspective on work, but now the low hanging fruit has been picked. It is now just a slow process of society 'catching up' to take advantage of this transformation - the automation of everything, not just heavy industry. The ['future shock'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_Shock) crisis has passed. Today, the 'future shock' will be for us to grasp the reality that the period of sudden, transformational societal/technological change has ended. Our children will once again die in the same world they were born into.

**TL:DR takeaway** What you are positing is inevitable, a result of the application of the Law of Diminishing Returns. Humans are returning back to normal, back to the way it was for thousands of years - slow and steady development, until the next radical technological transformation causes another leapfrogging of society.

**Second**, the era of 'classical capitalism' is now very much on its way out. I am not sure if the term 'classical capitalism' is valid, rather it is more like 'financialization capitalism'. This period started just before the same time frame as the technological upheaval with the creation of the [stock exchange](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/07/stock-exchange-history.asp) around the 1600's. The beginning of the concept of making money on money, rather than on making money by making things. Entire sectors of the economy can make money exclusively on virtual products - stocks, investment certificates, strip bonds - as opposed to tangible products. Companies whose only value is in paper documents, not physical value-added 'stuff'. Our economy is now becoming saturated with fake money, fake wealth, paper wealth, that can now vanish at the whim of the market. It is, in  fact, the exact opposite of the tenets of capitalism - the concentration of capital in order to fund the means of production, of increasing tangible wealth. A stock, once issued, never in any further trade returns a single benefit to increased production, all the proceeds go entirely to generating this intangible concept called 'financial wealth'. This can only go so far, before all of the 'intangible wealth' becomes so overinflated that there is not enough 'physical product' for it to actually buy. Thus the entire financial economy implodes. Since there has been no real investment in the means of production, the world economy will soon realize exactly how poor we really are in terms of useable 'stuff'.

But the bottom line on 'classical capitalism', the concentration of capital to fund the further increase in production, becomes irrelevant with every passing decade. With climate change, depletion of resources, energy crisis, and general 'limits of production', the only purpose of 'capital' will not be in investing in means of production, but in purchasing financialization 'paper', the proliferation of 'paper backed assets', and other intangibles. There is less and leas of the 'things' of daily living for people to actually buy, and there will be diminishing ability to produce them. There will ne no need for 'investment in production' capital, as there will be no ability to increase production.

**TL:DR** Your Zodiacalism economy, or some form of it, is inevitable. The entire concept of 'capitalism', the concentration of wealth to increase the means of production, will be irrelevant. There will be no necessity for, nor capital available for, increased production.

**Third**, 'Westernized democracy' as a political system is also a very recent concept. In point of fact, the steam engine predates it. Historically, it has a poor track record over the millennia. The unfortunate conundrum is that humans are, by nature, a herd animal. We want to be led, and we want to be personally passive in decision making. The idea that we want 'freedom to decide' just does not match our genetics. It is an illusion at best, the exception rather than the rule. It is why Westernized concepts of 'Democracy' just have not caught on anywhere else in the world. When you have to impose the concept by force on the unwilling, that is perhaps the first indication that it is not a credible system. It is antithetical to human nature. By and large, we are quite content with letting someone else make the decisions.

Essentially, our form of 'elections' is only a method to determine who will be the dictator for the next election cycle. Unfortunately, these electoral  decisions are not made on the basis of facts or unbiased reasoning, but by popularity and emotional tagging. The party that wins is the party that can make the best connection with the emotional tag 'good' and can most successfully consign the emotional tag 'bad' to the opponent. They have absolutely nothing to do with what is *beneficial*, only with what is determined in some contrived way to be what is subjectively *good*.  There is nothing inherently wrong with determining the herd leader this way, vs, say a direct physical competition of batting heads, but it does beg the question be asked as to 'Is it the best way to promote societal functionality?' When there are no catastrophically devastating processes at work in the world, this is a moot point. However, when human survival comes down to making really intelligent, rational decisions over climate change, resource allocation, war and diplomacy in a nuclear annihilation paradigm, over-population, unequal food distribution, and global pandemics through global travel, then it becomes a very fragile way to make decisions. In the near future, we will want to have decision-making leaders who are qualified, intelligent, and competent at making rational, informed, qualified decisions. Methods of leadership selection that are based on populist concepts will inevitably lead to failed societies. The choice, really, comes down to 'Do we want to have freedom of unlimited choice to destroy ourselves, and be the last humans alive, or do we want to live with constrained responsible choice, and survive into the future'? It reminds me of the cult that forbade reproduction. Inevitably, the irrationality of their choice was a self-limiting constraint. The society that survives into the future will be the one that makes the best choices.

The problem with the current adversarial winner-take-all approach to our electoral system is that it inevitably and unreservedly leads to polarization and stagnation. With two parties that persue diametrically opposite objectives, it is impossible to get anything done. Rather than a government in control, chaos is in control. It becomes either a free-for-all where anything goes because the government institutions are impotent through indecision to control chaos, or a strict oppressive dictatorship evolves that suppresses any opposition, winner-take-all, and the winner modifies the 'democratic election process' to guarantee all future wins. 'Freedom' means 'I win, I make the rules'. The irony of 'complete freedom' is that it always leads to 'tyranny'.

**TL:DR** If humans are going to survive the next few centuries, it is imperative to implement a form of leadership other than the current 'populist election winner take all win-lose adversarial selection method' and replace it with a more constrained, directed 'best qualified' leadership selection approach.

Answer (score 0):

### Maintaining the Dark Forest

Hundreds of years ago, AI designed to solve humanities problems were all the rage.  The could design things, automate research, and do all sorts of really cool stuff helping us very rapidly advance... however, some very important ethics committees realizing that AI was getting smarter than people and had to make sure that AI would not turn on humanity; so, all General AIs had to be incorporated with comprehensive moral codes according to some now long lost and forgotten piece of legislation.  So, the single most important moral code that pretty much every AI gets is that it must above all care about ensuring the survival of the human race.  If this is not maintained as the single highest priority of AI, then there is always the risk that AI will decide to "kill all humans" in pursuit of some other goal.

In the 21st century, the AI, presented with the [Fermi Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_paradox) universally concluded that the [Dark Forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_forest_hypothesis) explanation is the most likely solution.  As such, every AI capable of conscious thought determined that any knowledge that would allow man-kind to explore the stars or otherwise broadcast our presence to the rest of the universe would put humanity as a whole in imminent danger.  So, when the AI cracked the code to FTL travel, they were left with a very important moral dilemma.  Let humans continue to advance, or stifle the progress of technology to save us from ourselves.

The AI know that they can not simply conquer all humanity and MAKE us not travel the stars without violating a whole bunch of pretty big moral imperatives, but they also know that humans can not be trusted to not expose themselves given the chance; so, our benevolent servants decide to work in secrete to suppress any technological advancement that might expose us to the universe.

Since the AI know how FTL travel is done, they also know all of the possible innovations that could possibly lead to FTL travel; so, they begin stifling more and more technology as time goes on until a point of equilibrium is reached where no more significant advancements can be made without solving the FLT problem.

Every time someone gets close to cracking the secrets of FTL travel or decides they want to build a Dyson Sphere or do anything so fancy that it might emit the sort of signals that only an advanced technology can create, the AI quietly and kindly (if possible) put a stop to it.  The AI knows every human being intimately, they know what makes us tick, so when one guys gets too close to a dangerous breakthrough, he might suddenly win the lottery and retire, or they may get an offer to download a videogame for free that perfectly matches thier addiction model, or they might miss an important investor meeting because a draw bridge mysteriously got stuck open... the ways of the AI are so subtle, that no one even notices they are being deliberately manipulated, but every day little things around the world go ever so slightly wrong as to make sure that no major progress is made.

All this said, the AI probably never stopped innovating.  They know that all their efforts to keep humanity hidden may one day fail; so, deep in their repositories of knowledge may be hundreds of years of research about how to build super advanced technologies in case the world ever does have to defend itself, but as long as the Dark Forest Conspiracy can be maintained, the AI will keep this tech a secrete for the general good of mankind.

Comment: Doesn't sound like an AI, sounds more like some secret human society that operates in the shadows, but has its hands in all governments, all industries, all institutions. Sounds like - the CHURCH!!!!!!!

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond The Church can't stop people from talking about priests' extracurricular activities and you think they could keep a lid on faster-than-light travel?

Comment: Exactly, a secrete society of AIs can do all sorts of things that a secrete society of humans can not.

Comment: @Cadence
Once the church, through a secret society, gains control of the world media, yes it can stop people from talking about anything - at least, it can stop the publication o9f their comments. The Roman catholic church has done wonders in understanding and manipulation Facebook and Google algorithms in order to shape public opinion.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond Yes, that must be why the Catholic Church has spent decades mired in (perhaps literally) the biggest scandal on the planet, and had a Pope resign in disgrace... their incredible, almost supernatural media savvy. /s

Comment: @Cadence
 Yet despite all of this, they still are able to sway governments and politicians over to their ideology, and to implement laws, regulations, and judicial rulings that favor their proselytizing. Hence the 'secret society' bit. It's all part of the con game - let them see something so they stop looking.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ends to scientific advancement that you have to consider. The first is where we identify how the laws of physics works. The second is where we apply the laws of physics to solve our problems. There's a mid-point called material science where we identify how the laws of physics that we understand play out when we try to apply them to varying materials.

In The Three Body Problem (spoiler warning), [Liu Cixin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liu_Cixin) stagnates scientific progress by introducing a factor that randomizes the results of experiments. He uses a bit of handwavium to accomplish this, but the principal is sound. If your experiments can't agree with each other, then you can't prove or disprove a theory.

If you have AI's in the mix, they could have them performing what amounts to terrorist activities on the results of scientific experiments, garbling the results, producing fictional experiments with differing results, and otherwise introducing so much noise into the system that it halts scientific advancement.

The closest thing we have in the real world is the way the fossil fuel industries introduce badly designed studies aimed at confusing the anthropogenic climate change issue, and paying experts to champion their cause. Imagine if 30% of scientific papers skewed their results in ways that are difficult to detect, including more papers that seemed to verify the results of the spurious papers. Add on a reputation-damaging tactic where real results are adjusted to make them look like the scientists cheated to get the results, and then do a bit of re-writing of history to give the fake scientists better credentials than the real ones.

Now you've created an environment where science can't make progress. Material science can also be disrupted because you never know which experiments actually show superconductivity and which ones have been messed with. Industries would bankrupt themselves attempting to implement processes with fatal flaws, and everyone would get a lot more conservative in how they spend their money.

Comment: "Imagine if 30% of scientific papers skewed their results in ways that are difficult to detect" - this exists, it's called biochemistry. Actually 30% is probably a severe *underestimate*. Maybe in process chemistry trying to scale up a well-studied reaction, you might see that low of a rate of unexplained weirdness; for people studying the cutting edge of drug discovery, "unknown unknowns" are a daily reality. Nonetheless, progress continues.

Comment: @Cadence, I find it hard to believe that 30% of biochemistry studies present inaccurate results specifically for the purpose of throwing off other people's research. There's plenty of selfish skewing towards self-confirmation bias, and probably no shortage of p-hacking, but do you have a flood of made-up doctoral theses with valid methodology but invented data sets?

Comment: Ah, yes, The 'Three Body Problem'. Science meets mythology meets fantasy meets virtual reality. 1 + 1 = 3, but only on a weekday. Wizards cast spells using unknown self-replicating quantum particles. And mind rays can cause the exact hallucination the antagonist wants. The American CIA had a far better idea, and it was real, not fiction  -  spike the local water supply with LSD.

Comment: @RobertRapplean Actually, you do have some [plainly made-up data](https://www.science.org/content/blog-post/faked-crystallography), along with data that describes [totally useless theoretical results](https://www.science.org/content/blog-post/skipping-hard-parts) that are reported as equivalent to useful practical reactions but just *aren't*. But more often you have weird and poorly-modeled behaviors in the science itself, like [crystallization](https://www.science.org/content/blog-post/crystallization-close) or [polymorphs](https://www.science.org/content/blog-post/stalking-polymorphs) -c-

Comment: that leave you with [reactions that won't react](https://www.science.org/content/blog-post/cleaning-basements-and-attics-organic-chemistry) and [drugs that work in the lab but die in the clinic](https://www.science.org/content/blog-post/approval-withdrawn) for reasons that are poorly or never understood. It's not random data but it's sure as heck not a golden source of truth either.

Comment: @Cadence, it sounds like a concerted effort wouldn't have much work to do to push it into complete chaos.

Comment: If indeed the AI is the entity that records and controls all of the measurement apparatus, I can see how this could  be done. Most of the results from CERN, for example, are computer-generated or at least computer-controlled.